# How to use iOS Charts when pulling in multiple data from an array?

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

I have been learning to use iOS Charts over the past few days and have successfully gotten to them work when dealing with 'single' data called in from an API.

However I am now stuck because I want to pull in multiple data from an array.

My aim is to create a Bar Chart based on the `winning_streak` of each `user_name` in the array below:

```
["leagueStats": {
winningStreak =     (
            {
        id = 2;
        "user_name" = Dicky;
        "winning_streak" = 5;
    },
            {
        id = 6;
        "user_name" = G;
        "winning_streak" = 2;
    },
            {
        id = 5;
        "user_name" = Sultan;
        "winning_streak" = 0;
    }
);
}
]
```

This is my code that retrieves the API:

**This is where I need help  - Do I need to produce some kind of loop?
In the answer supplied the amount of users to appear in the graph is pre-programmed.**

**With my current code below it only picks out the first object in the array.  How do I get it to cycle through the array and populate the desired variables?**

```
   if let dict = json?["leagueStats"] as? [String:AnyObject] {

                        // WINNING STREAK

                        if let dataWinStreak = dict["winningStreak"] as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
                            let newdictWinStreak = dataWinStreak.first! // I'm guess this needs to be removed and this section re-structured?

                            let tempWinStreakNumber = newdictWinStreak ["winning_streak"] as? String
                            let tempWinStreakNewNumber = Int(tempWinStreakNumber!)
                            let doubleWinStreak = Double(tempWinStreakNewNumber!)

                            self.winStreak = doubleWinStreak
                            self.winningStreak =  ["Wins"]

                            let games = [self.winStreak]
                            self.setWinStreakChart(dataPoints: self.winningStreak, values: games)

                         }
```

However this code above only pulls in information from the first record in the array to use, `5`.

I want to be able to produce 3 different columns, `Dicky`, `G`, `Sultan`, with the corresponding values of `5`, `2`, and `0`.

This is my code for displaying the Bar Chart - currently just displaying 1 column, showing `5`.

```
func setWinStreakChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]){

    let formato:WinningStreakFormatter = WinningStreakFormatter()
    let xaxis:XAxis = XAxis()

    winningStreakBarChart.noDataText = "you need to provide some data for the chart."

    var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = Array()

    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: values[i])
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
        formato.stringForValue (Double(i), axis: xaxis)
    }

    xaxis.valueFormatter = formato
    winningStreakBarChart.xAxis.valueFormatter = xaxis.valueFormatter

    let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Games Played")
    let chartData = BarChartData(dataSets: [chartDataSet])

    chartData.addDataSet(chartDataSet)
    winningStreakBarChart.data = chartData

    winningStreakBarChart.xAxis.granularityEnabled = true
    winningStreakBarChart.xAxis.granularity = 1.0

    self.winningStreakBarChart.xAxis.labelPosition = XAxis.LabelPosition.bottom

}
```

This is what I have:

[image]

Ideally, what I want is the label 'Win Streak' to be the `user_name` from the API, then the legend `Games _Played` to say `Winning Streak`. In this particular instance, I want 3 columns for the 3 user_names in the array.

Once this is done, as a secondary objective I want to add another dataset for `Losing Streak` which would be grouped by the same `user_name`.

Could someone please show me how to do this? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WinningStreakFormatter` class is used to format xAxis labels, here I have used an approach of reusing the data from chart object as result `WinningStreakFormatter` have a weak reference to the chart view. So using this approach we can have data to be held by chart view rather than keeping an additional copy with `WinningStreakFormatter`

```
import Foundation
import Charts

class WinningStreakFormatter: NSObject, IAxisValueFormatter {

    weak var _chartView : BarChartView!

    init(chartView : BarChartView) {
        self._chartView = chartView
    }

    public func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
        let barChartData : IChartDataSet = (self._chartView.barData?.dataSets.first)!
        let barChartDataEntry : ChartDataEntry = barChartData.entryForIndex(Int(value))!
        return barChartDataEntry.data as! String
    }
}
```

Refer the code below in order to prepare the proposed chart, In below code chartView is basically the `BarChartView` type instance variable. Also, I have used the same data structure that you have in your API, you can simply replace dataPoints with your parsed data structure.

```
    self.chartView.drawBarShadowEnabled = false
    self.chartView.drawValueAboveBarEnabled = true
    self.chartView.chartDescription?.enabled = false

    let  xAxis : XAxis = self.chartView.xAxis;
    xAxis.labelFont = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 10.0)! 
    xAxis.labelTextColor = UIColor.black
    xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
    xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = true
    xAxis.granularity = 1;
    xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
    xAxis.valueFormatter = WinningStreakFormatter(chartView: self.chartView)

    let yAxisLeft : YAxis = self.chartView.leftAxis
    yAxisLeft.axisMinimum = 0.0

    let yAxisRight : YAxis = self.chartView.rightAxis
    yAxisRight.axisMinimum = 0.0

    let l : Legend = self.chartView.legend;
    l.horizontalAlignment = Legend.HorizontalAlignment.left
    l.verticalAlignment = Legend.VerticalAlignment.bottom
    l.orientation = Legend.Orientation.horizontal
    l.drawInside = false
    l.form = Legend.Form.square
    l.formSize = 9.0
    l.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 11.0)!
    l.xEntrySpace = 4.0

    //Data Structure built for each user for winning streak, you can use your parsing logic to prepare the same
    let winningStreakDM1 : [String : Any] = [
        "id" : 2,
        "user_name" : "Dicky",
        "winning_streak" : 5
    ]

    let winningStreakDM2 : [String : Any] = [
        "id" : 6,
        "user_name" : "G",
        "winning_streak" : 2
    ]

    let winningStreakDM3 : [String : Any] = [
        "id" : 5,
        "user_name" : "Sultan",
        "winning_streak" : 0
    ]


    //Array of the each user winning streak dictionary.
    let dataPoints = [winningStreakDM1, winningStreakDM2, winningStreakDM3]

    var values = [BarChartDataEntry]()

    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        let xValue = Double(i)
        let yValue = Double(dataPoints[i]["winning_streak"] as! Int)

        let barChartDataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: xValue, y: yValue, data: dataPoints[i]["user_name"] as AnyObject)
        values.append(barChartDataEntry)
    }

    let barChartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: values, label: "Winning Streak")
    barChartDataSet.colors = ChartColorTemplates.material()

    let barChartData = BarChartData(dataSet: barChartDataSet)
    barChartData.setValueFont(UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0))
    self.chartView.data = barChartData
```

[image: Output of the above sample code.]

Comment: Thanks Prakash - i am nearly there :)  my last hurdle is the winningStreakDM's in your answer are pre-programmed (i.e 3 users).  
How do I cycle through my array to populate the winningStreakDM's?  In my code above it only takes the first object out of the array and I do not know how to cycle through to achieve my aim.   I have updated the question with reference to this point. Thanks

Comment: @RDowns You have to iterate through your array of `winningStreak` and prepare the winningStreakDM's or you can simply replace `dataPoints` to `winningStreak` array in for loop to prepare `BarChartDataEntry` objects.

Comment: Do I need to create a struct and a flatMap to do this? Or am I now going down the wrong route?

Comment: @RDowns `dict["winningStreak"]` is basically array so `let dataPoints = dict["winningStreak"]` will full fill your requirement.